State Restoration while Using GetX in Flutter
Currently the GetX plugin's GetMaterialApp does come with the restorationId we need for state restoration. So I am facing quite an issue here, specially in phones with low memory while using imagePicker or cunning document scanner plugin. Is there a way around this ?
